# How to stop public seeing error messages in PHP

Tags: php, security

Pretty much if i mistake does happen in my php i do not want the public to see the error for security purposes, is there anyway of having like a log or file that only people with that file or access can see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following line as the first line:

```
   error_reporting(0);
```

Another alternative is the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set the flag with php_flag log_errors on, 
then use php_value error_log *path to log file*

To suppress warnings/errors you can use 
php_flag display_errors off